# Accessing elements of a list within a dictionary component wise

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

Let's say I have a dictionary (MxN = 4x3 matrix) that has keys of integers and values of lists as follows:

```
d={1:[10,11,12], 2:[13,14,15], 3:[16,17,18], 4:[19,20,21]}
```

I am trying to get a list that looks like this:

```
new_list_1 = [10,13,16,19]
```

In this case, I am trying to get the first element of each value (list) in the dictionary and put it into a new list. However, I would also like to do this for other indexes as well such as:

```
new_list_2 = [11,14,17,20]
```

or

```
new_list_3 = [12,15,18,21]
```

Once I have these lists, ideally I would like to them in a new dictionary of dimension NxM :

```
d_new = {0:new_list_1, 1:new_list_2, 2:new_list_3}
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe conver it to `numpy.array` or `pandas.DataFrame` and then you can get first column `array[:,0]`, second column `array[:,1]`, etc. And you can even convert all columns to rows - transpose matrix - `d_new = array.T`

Comment: Thanks for the input - this is similar to Trace Malloc's approach. I like the idea of taking the transpose for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas as well:

```
import pandas as pd

d_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient = 'index').to_dict('list')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I really like the simplicity and readability of this solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
new_list_1 = [v[0] for v in d.values()]
new_list_2 = [v[1] for v in d.values()]
new_list_3 = [v[2] for v in d.values()]
```

then use

```
d_new = {0:new_list_1, 1:new_list_2, 2:new_list_3}
```

Value of `d_new` :

```
{0: [10, 13, 16, 19], 1: [11, 14, 17, 20], 2: [12, 15, 18, 21]}
```

Alternatively:

```
d_new = {i:[v[i] for v in d.values()] for i in range(0,3)}
```

Would also do the same

Comment: What is `n0`, `n1`, and `n2`? They are not defined. Also would prefer to loop through the keys instead of manually creating the lists.

Comment: @Transcending its `v[0]`, `v[1]` and `v[2]`

Comment: @Transcending I have also attached a one liner that can do it without multiple lists

Comment: Thanks - ideally I would like it less hard-coded for the `range(0,3)` part in case the dictionary has higher dimension.

Comment: @Transcending for higher dimension use `range(0,N)` in the current case MxN `N` is 3

Comment: `range(len(d)-1)` can also be an alternative

Answer (score 2):

convert your dict values to list of list (2d matrix) and then use transpose of that matrix and then make the result according to your needs.

```
res =  {i: list(k) for i ,k in enumerate(list(zip(*d.values())))} 
print(res)
# {0: [10, 13, 16, 19], 1: [11, 14, 17, 20], 2: [12, 15, 18, 21]}
```

Answer (score 2):

With numpy you can:

```
import numpy as np
d = {
    1: [10, 11, 12],
    2: [13, 14, 15],
    3: [16, 17, 18],
    4: [19, 20, 21],
}
a = np.array(list(d.values()))
a = a.T
```

Output:

```
array([[10, 13, 16, 19],
       [11, 14, 17, 20],
       [12, 15, 18, 21]])
```

Back to dict:

```
d = {n+1: l for n, l in enumerate(a.tolist())}
```

Output:

```
{1: [10, 13, 16, 19], 2: [11, 14, 17, 20], 3: [12, 15, 18, 21]}
```

Comment: Good call! My brain is so fried, I didn't even realize I was looking for the transpose. This also seems very efficient.

Comment: @Transcending thanks....added the conversion back to a dict, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply like so:

```
d_new = {}
for i in range(len(list(d.values())[0])):
    d_new[i] = [x[i] for x in d.values()]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy to understand:

```
d={1:[10,11,12], 2:[13,14,15], 3:[16,17,18], 4:[19,20,21]}
d_new = {}
for i in range(len(d[1])):
    l = []
    for v in d.values():
        l.append(v[i])
    d_new[i] = l
print(d_new)
```

output:

```
{0: [10, 13, 16, 19], 1: [11, 14, 17, 20], 2: [12, 15, 18, 21]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
lista_1 = []
lista_2 = []
lista_3 = []
d_new = {}
for i in d.values():
  for h, j in enumerate(i):
    if h == 0:
      lista_1.append(j)
      d_new[h] = lista_1
    elif h == 1:
      lista_2.append(j)
      d_new[h] = lista_2
    else:
      lista_3.append(j)
      d_new[h] = lista_3
```

Output :

```
{0: [10, 13, 16, 19], 1: [11, 14, 17, 20], 2: [12, 15, 18, 21]}
```

Maybe this can help you, it is for beginners' understanding!